# Windows 7 freezes when all DIMMs are full

Tags: windows-7, memory, freeze, dell-dimension

I have an old Dell Dimension C521 (0HY175 mobo) which I've upgraded as a budget family PC (homework/bit of gaming on older games etc - I already have a couple of consoles for later games and I have an i7 based laptop which I use for anything else)

It originally had a single 512 DIMM in there, which I've since replaced with 4 x 1GB modules, however, this results in Windows 7 not being able to boot

I get the "Starting Windows" screen, but it freezes during that animation (in pretty much the same place every time).

This also happens during the "Starting Windows" bar on the Windows 7 installer.

The PC boots fine and detects all 4 DIMMs, but will only ever boot into Windows with a maximum of 3 modules installed.

I've tried swapping the modules in all sorts of combinations, which rules out a faulty module (I even tried with the original 512 module in place of one of the 1Gb ones and it still fails to boot but only when all 4 are full). The system seems to correctly detect the RAM in the BIOS.

I've tried changing all the BIOS settings, there don't appear to be any voltage settings in the BIOS though, so all I can do is turn on/off bits and pieces such as the USB ports, SMART status, HD settings, Cool & Quiet etc.

This is Windows 7 64bit Home edition (since I can't run the installer I'd imagine this is also an issue with 32bit)

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

So some online reading reveals that 2GB sticks should work even though the board specifies a max of 4 x 1GB (8GB is possible apparently via 2GB modules), I've got a couple of 2GB sticks on order.

Putting 2 x 1GB in the first two slots successfully works in dual channel mode, so maybe the second channel is the issue or the BIOS needs an update.

I'll update when I receive the RAM tomorrow.

**edit**

The plot doth thicken, I received the two sticks of 2gb and though the BIOS recognises them windows will not boot unless I remove one of the sticks.

This persists with both sticks in in single or dual channel mode

I tested dual channel boot with my 1gb sticks and it worked fine so it's windows that just won't boot with more than 3gb ram - it always freezes on startup (even the setup CD freezes)

I might try installing xp if I can find a copy, but essentially my issue lies in windows and possibly windows 7 drivers for this motherboard.

The PC originally came with windows xp and said it was "vista upgradeable"

Anyone else have any ideas?

**edit**

Also tried windows XP which boots fine (albeit with 3.5gb showing in windows)

Windows 8 also fails to install/boot unless under 4gb is present...

Comment: Are all the DIMM's *IDENTICAL*? These early DDR2 Dual Channel motherboards often had problems with mis-matched memory DIMMs... if every DIMM wasn't absolutely identical and the proper pairing done, problems often occurred after the OS would start loading. At the very least pair 1 must be identical and pair 2 must be identical, on this board it means slots 1&2 must match exactly, and slots 3&4 must match exactly. This appears to be this issue because it works with only 3 DIMMs, which forces the board into single channel memory mode which works.

Comment: What is your motherboard's model?

Comment: Down voting should be accompanied by a comment really...

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for the info but they are all matched modules I bought together and I've tried them in different configurations (I.e. every combination you can possibly use). What are the chances it's a problem with dual channel mode regardless of the ram?

Comment: The motherboard is a CN-0HY175-70821-715-K1C0. Which probably only comes in a Dell C521

Comment: @Charleh TBH,  the chances are better than zero...  There was a lot of incompatibility issues in early DDR2 dual channel chipsets... Especially with 800Mhz DIMMs. Early chipsets supported 533/667Mhz OK, but when 800Mhz was introduced soon after there was lots of compatibility issues. Sorry I don't have an answer, and I don't think that motherboard has manual ram timing options, so other than making sure BIOS is the latest available the best you can do is try some different DIMM from different manufacturers perhaps.

Comment: Well, it only cost me a bit and I've got 3 gig working so it's not all bad!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's the weird thing - I couldn't get the thing to boot no matter what I did when over 3GB was installed (even 3.5 GB) up to 4GB

Anything over 4GB **will boot!** - so I've got a total of 6GB of ram in there and Windows is up in a couple of seconds...

No idea what's going on there...if anyone is having the same issue, try something counter-intuitive and *add more RAM* (if you have it)

All the memory is running in dual channel mode now, I'll just keep the 2 x 2GB and the 2 x 1GB sticks and call it a day :)